# Which one of the following showing the correct structure Jsmol or Vesta? Or they are just same

Tags: computational-chemistry, software, vesta, databases

Let me explain. I found that the structure for TiFeSi given in the ICSD database using Jsmol software is a little different from what can be obtained using Vesta software using the same cif file downloaded from the ICSD data base. Some atoms in the Vesta plot are missing e.g. Si (corresponding to the Si1 and Ti3 in the Jsmol plot)
[image]
Is it a glitch or bug of Vesta or these two representations are just the same? If they are just the same then how?

Comment: Could you please provide the CIF file or a link to it? thanks!

Comment: It looks to me like Jsmol is showing the periodic repeats for atoms on the cell boundaries, whereas Vesta is only showing the unique positions. The simplest check is to compare the stoichiometry of the material with the visible atoms - Vesta should match the stoichiometry, whereas Jsmol should have extra atoms. Now get Vesta to display a supercell, and look at the atoms in the original lattice - you should see all the atoms Jsmol is showing. In any case, it's not a bug it's just a difference in visualisation philosophy.